# Tools to recover data from a BtrFS partition whose first sectors were overwritten

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

The first few GBs of my 300 GB BtrFS partition were overwritten by another file system, so I lost that data. Naturally, the partition cannot be mounted as BtrFS, so none of the contents I want to recover can be accessed in a normal way; however, most of the data is still there, intact.

- I have already attempted to recover files using `photorec`, with some success, and I would like to know about alternative data recovery tools for BtrFS, which may give better results.

What tools do you recommend?

Comment: I'd try testdisk, and see if you can't pull the entire partition.

Comment: What is 'pulling' a partition? He said he OVERWROTE first GB's of the partition, testdisk will recreate partition table and so will do nothing for sustained damage.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably SOL; you might be able to do something by trying to find the third superblock, but [don't hold your breath](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213689).

- To attempt restoring from the second superblock (else follow the Advanced Usage section):

  ```bsh
  btrfs -u 2 restore "/dev/sdX" "/path/to/save/filesto"
  ```

Answer (score -1):

There are several, though all the programs I'm familiar with are not freeware. Still, I believe some offer full functionality during a free trail period. I've used the following programs which will recover any data that hasn't been overwritten multiple times and shouldn't be affected by a missing first sector as far as I know:

1. Stellar Phoenix Data OR Photo Recovery
2. Wondershare Recovery
3. EaseUS Data OR Photo Recovery
4. Easy Photo Recovery
5. Recuva - An App from CCleaner

Stellar Phoenix seems to rank above all of these when researching on the internet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: These are popular though low grade tools and I doubt they support BtrFS. UFS Explorer, ReclaiMe would be better options, DMDE maybe even.

Answer (score -1):

Use a tool that 'understands' BTRFS and you may be able to virtually reconstruct the file system and recover files with file names and folder structure intact.

Tools I know of that support (virtual) BTRFS file system reconstruction are:

- DMDE, dmde.com, this is the most inexpensive one
- ReclaiMe*, reclaime.com, super easy to use
- UFS Explorer, ufsexplorer.com

(*) - This tool requires Windows as host OS.